# Implementing MVC architecture using AngularJS in Web application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, gulp

I implemented AngularJS: MVC structure in my web application.
My project is the following structure.

```
-Package
    |_app
         |_build
         |_home
               |_controllers(HomeCtrl.js)
               |_modules(HomeResources.js)
               |_views(home.html)
               |_module.js
         |_bower_components(all javascript libraries are here)
         |_app.scripts.json
         |_bower.json
         |_gulpfile.js
         |_index.html
```

I used gulp to build the project and try to load home's home.html into index.html. After building using gulp, I have app.js inside build folder and load into index.html as follow.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" class="no-js">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>BnLMyanmar</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content=""> 

    </head>     
    <body>

        <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>     
        <script src="build/app.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

But contents of home.html are not displayed on the webpage when the application is run.

The full source code can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212117/testing-a-web-application-using-angularjs-mvc-implementation) .

Why I can't display the contents of home.html at the home page?

Thanks

Comment: have you added angularjs script?

Comment: You `index.html` has no body

Comment: You appear to be minifying your code but not using the square bracket notation. That will cause errors. Also why di you have two questions asking the same thing?

Comment: @Araz yes angularjs was loaded in the app.scripts.json. Please look at gulpfile.js and task vendor in the gulpfile. Inside this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212117/testing-a-web-application-using-angularjs-mvc-implementation).

Comment: @ste2425 May I know where?

Comment: The uglify module in your gulp task is minifying your Js. Search for angular and minification.

Comment: @ste2425 I build in dev task, that has no uglify, has the same problem.